# Column 'ip' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `logins` (`ip`, `steamid`, `time`)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

```
insert into `logins` (`ip`, `steamid`, `time`)
```

I use **php7.0** and **phpmyadmin** on **vmware ubuntu server 16.04.6**
I tried to fix it myself but I'm not really good at those kind of things if you need any more code tell me.
any help if welcome

the site wont let me post the full code here is the [full code](https://pastebin.com/qeQ68CxK)

This is the `AuthController` code

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The SteamAuth instance.
     *
     * @var SteamAuth
     */
    protected $steam;

    /**
     * The redirect URL.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectURL = '192.168.1.12';

    /**
     * AuthController constructor.
     * 
     * @param SteamAuth $steam
     */
    public function __construct(SteamAuth $steam)
    {
        $this->steam = $steam;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the authentication page
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function redirectToSteam()
    {
        return $this->steam->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Get user info and log in
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if($this->steam->validate())
        {
            $info = $this->steam->getUserInfo();
            $findUser = DB::table('users')->where('steamid', $info->steamID64)->first();
            if(is_null($findUser))
            {

                $hasThisIp = DB::table('users')->where('ip', $this->getIp())->count();

                if(!is_null($hasThisIp)) {

                    $connections =  json_decode(json_encode($hasThisIp), true);

                    if($connections > 3) return view('connections');
                    else {
                        $array = array('<','>');
                        $numele = $info->personaname;
                        $name = str_replace($array, '*', $numele);
                        DB::table('users')->insert(
                            [
                                'name' => $name,
                                'steamid' => $info->steamID64,
                                'avatar' => $info->avatarfull,
                                'token' => csrf_token(),
                                'ip' => $this->getIp()
                            ]
                        );
```

Comment: why don't you try `request()->ip()` instead of `$this->getIp()` if you only need the ip address

Comment: Please check inside User Model 'ip' is added in fillable array.